# Delaying the loop (countdown func)

Tags: ios, swift, for-loop, delay

I've looked at many articles, none of the answers are correct. I know that these methods work, but inside a for-loop they don't. How can I create a countdown func - where I can print an array with a one second delay in between.

```
let array = [9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

I tried this:

```
for n in array {
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
                print(n)
            }
        }
```

And it prints **all the numbers** after 1 second. So I tried this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 2, target: self, selector: (#selector(printer)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

@objc func printer() {
    for n in array {
       print(n)
        }
    }
```

Same result. I guess these are good methods, but something's wrong.

Comment: If you want to print the numbers at different times then you should use different offsets in `asyncAfter(deadline:)`

Comment: Possibly duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49974984/pause-loop-iteration-in-swift

Comment: @AhmadF : If you see this as a duplicate question, please do that by Closing the question. That way you don't have to explicitly write - Possible duplicate of. It would itself appear as a comment.

Comment: @Nitish I am not aiming to vote to close it, since I'm unsure about being the exact case for OP, nevertheless I mentioned it in case if its useful... Thanks for the note btw :)

Comment: @AhmadF : I see. Appreciate !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a counter variable and another variable for the timer

```
var counter = 0
var timer : Timer?
```

In `viewDidLoad` create the timer

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(printer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}
```

In the action method increment the `counter` variable and invalidate the timer if the number of items in the array is reached.

```
@objc func printer() {

    print(array[counter])
    counter += 1
    if counter == array.count {
       timer?.invalidate()
       timer = nil
    }
}
```

Another way is `DispatchSourceTimer`, it avoids the `@objc` runtime

```
var timer : DispatchSourceTimer?

let interval : DispatchTime = .now() + .seconds(1)

timer = DispatchSource.makeTimerSource(queue: DispatchQueue.global())
timer!.schedule(deadline:interval, repeating: 1)
var index = 0
timer!.setEventHandler {
    // DispatchQueue.main.async {
       print(array[index])
    }
    index += 1
    if index == array.count {
        timer!.cancel()
        timer = nil
    }
}
timer!.resume()
```

Comment: This is just for my clarification - Why is this a better solution than @a.masri solution ?

Comment: Using `sleep` is pretty bad habit because it blocks the current thread. `Timer` works asynchronously.

Comment: I guess all the 3 answers are correct. That one, even though it contains more code, is the clearest for me - it has the Timer, runs outside func, and stops the timer. However, it does not use for-loop.

Comment: @Kowboj A `for` loop is the wrong design in this case.

Comment: Not exactly. @SH_Khan's solution does not work. Also, it is not the question that which is correct but rather which is better. So let's see on that.

Comment: @vadian : I suspect that user wants to do anything asynchronously during this countdown.

Comment: It does work, and it actually solves one of my problems (understanding the asyncAfer method), which was also written in a comment to the question by @Martin-r

Comment: @Kowboj : But that prints all the elements all at once. I myself have checked that by implementing in the code.

Comment: @Nitish Martin means something like `for (index, n) in array.enumerated() { DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .seconds(index)) { print(n) }}`

Comment: I am sorry, why is Martin being tagged here ? @vadian : You have to edit that comment for better understanding.

Answer (score 1):

For loop runs all dispatches nearly at the same time , so all of them with the same waiting Time you can depend it like this

```
let array = [9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
  for i in 0...array.count-1 {
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + Double(i) ) {
        print(array[i])
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I made countdown this way. Don't know if it is the right way, but it works.

```
var timeRemaining: Int = 60

countdown()

func countdown() {
    if self.timeRemaining > 0 {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1 ) {
            self.timeRemaining -= 1
            self.countdown()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
let array = [9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]

    DispatchQueue.global().async {
        for n in array {
            sleep(1)
            print(n)
        }  
    }
```

When you use  this `DispatchQueue` is incorrect because it will be held by waiting and then print all

Comment: I'm not the down voter, but I can guess that your answer was down voted because it blocks the thread. If you run this on the main thread, your interface would freeze for 9 seconds.

Comment: @JeremyP This was not clarified by questions , basically you can use
for loop in  `DispatchQueue.globel`

Comment: It doesn't matter which thread you use, you are using that thread for 9 seconds to do a minimal amount of work as well as the fact that `sleep()` only guarantees the thread will sleep for *at least* a second which means your timing gets progressively more skewed. The solution of @vadian doesn't hog a thread and will give more accurate intervals.

Comment: @a.masri: it was specified, not in the question but by the tags. OP tagged [iOS] and no-one wants a blocked app.

Comment: @vikingosegundo I have edited  the answer but let's look at the question he is doing on the main Thread  and in the Tag he did not mention it